# Calculo de Media com JavaScript no Atom

Tags: javascript, editor-de-texto, atom

Boa Tarde pessoal tenho um exercício onde devo calcular as medias dos alunos, esse o calculo  deve ser feito automaticamente, para isso existe uma tabelas com 5 alunos,e cada um deles possui duas notas,as quais devem ser somadas e a partir delas devo informar a média,as notas já estão fixas na tabela...o que preciso é que quando a minha página da web estiver associada ao Javascript,a página ao ser aberta as médias já apareçam na tabela.

Como devo fazer isso usando o JavaScript..usando apenas o programa **Atom**? Ou seja **irei apenas usar o editor de textos!**

Abaixo está a imagem do site.. E ali nas médias que estão zeradas preciso que apresentem os valores da médias de cada aluno - isso quando eu associar a pagina web ao arquivo js

sei que no arquivo do java devo criar uma variável que seleciona a classe da média e depois devo fazer os cálculos.. e é ai que esta minha dificuldade não sei como fazer isso

[image: os zeros devem "virar" as médias]

**Código do JS que pensei para as médias e em seguida meu código HTML**

```js
var info-media = document.querySelector(".info-media")
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Suas Notas Notaveis</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="icone.ico" type="image/x-icon">


</head>
<body>
<header>
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="titulo">Notas Notáveis</h1>
   </div>

</header>
<main>
<section class="container">
  <p class="paragrafo1">Bem Vindo Aluno(a)</p>
  <p class="paragrafo2">Esse Site Apresenta Sua Notas</p>
  <p class="paragrafo3">Suas Notas somadas irão resultar na sua média! </p>
  <p class="paragrafo4">Confira Suas Notas Abaixo:</p>

  <h2 class="firsth2"> Podemos calcular sua média?</h2>


  <h2 class="secondh2">Minhas Notas</h2>
    <table border="1">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Nome</th>
       <th>Nota1</th>
       <th>Nota2</th>
       <th>Média</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>

          <tbody id="notas">
           <tr class="aluno" id="primeiro-aluno" >
             <td class="info-nome">Ana</td>
             <td class="info-nota1">7.0</td>
             <td class="info-nota2">8.00</td>
             <td class="info-media">0</td>
           </tr>

           <tr class="aluno" id="segundo-aluno" >
             <td class="info-nome">Caio</td>
             <td class="info-nota1">4.5</td>
             <td class="info-nota2">5.5</td>
             <td class="info-media">0</td>
           </tr>

           <tr class="aluno" id="terceiro-aluno" >
             <td class="info-nome">Daniela</td>
             <td class="info-nota1">6.6</td>
             <td class="info-nota2">6.0</td>
             <td class="info-media">0</td>
           </tr>

           <tr class="aluno" id="quarto-aluno" >
             <td class="info-nome">Laura</td>
             <td class="info-nota1">3.2</td>
             <td class="info-nota2">2.00</td>
             <td class="info-media">0</td>
           </tr>

           <tr class="aluno" id="quinto-aluno" >
             <td class="info-nome">Marcos</td>
             <td class="info-nota1">9.0</td>
             <td class="info-nota2">9.5</td>
             <td class="info-media">0</td>
           </tr>

        </table>
    </section>


</main>
     
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar qualquer editor de texto, porém deve salvar o arquivo com a extensão .html

Você pode inserir o seguinte script no final do seu código

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Pega todas as linhas com as notas dos alunos
    var alunos = document.querySelectorAll('.aluno');

    //Para cada linha pega a nota1 e nota 2, calcula a media e insere no campo info-media
    alunos.forEach(function(aluno){
      var nota1 = aluno.querySelector('.info-nota1').textContent;
      var nota2 = aluno.querySelector('.info-nota2').textContent;
      var media = (parseFloat(nota1) + parseFloat(nota2)) / 2;

      aluno.querySelector('.info-media').textContent = media;
    });
  </script>
```

Completo ele ficará assim:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Suas Notas Notaveis</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="icone.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="titulo">Notas Notáveis</h1>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section class="container">
      <p class="paragrafo1">Bem Vindo Aluno(a)</p>
      <p class="paragrafo2">Esse Site Apresenta Sua Notas</p>
      <p class="paragrafo3">Suas Notas somadas irão resultar na sua média! </p>
      <p class="paragrafo4">Confira Suas Notas Abaixo:</p>

      <h2 class="firsth2"> Podemos calcular sua média?</h2>


      <h2 class="secondh2">Minhas Notas</h2>
   <table border="1">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Nota1</th>
      <th>Nota2</th>
      <th>Média</th>
     </tr>
     </thead>

        <tbody id="notas">
         <tr class="aluno" id="primeiro-aluno" >
           <td class="info-nome">Ana</td>
           <td class="info-nota1">7.0</td>
           <td class="info-nota2">8.00</td>
           <td class="info-media">0</td>
         </tr>

         <tr class="aluno" id="segundo-aluno" >
           <td class="info-nome">Caio</td>
           <td class="info-nota1">4.5</td>
           <td class="info-nota2">5.5</td>
           <td class="info-media">0</td>
         </tr>

         <tr class="aluno" id="terceiro-aluno" >
           <td class="info-nome">Daniela</td>
           <td class="info-nota1">6.6</td>
           <td class="info-nota2">6.0</td>
           <td class="info-media">0</td>
         </tr>

         <tr class="aluno" id="quarto-aluno" >
           <td class="info-nome">Laura</td>
           <td class="info-nota1">3.2</td>
           <td class="info-nota2">2.00</td>
           <td class="info-media">0</td>
         </tr>

         <tr class="aluno" id="quinto-aluno" >
           <td class="info-nome">Marcos</td>
           <td class="info-nota1">9.0</td>
           <td class="info-nota2">9.5</td>
           <td class="info-media">0</td>
         </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </section>
  </main> 

  <script type="text/javascript">
    //Pega todas as linhas com as notas dos alunos
    var alunos = document.querySelectorAll('.aluno');

    //Para cada linha pega a nota1 e nota 2, calcula a media e insere no campo info-media
    alunos.forEach(function(aluno){
      var nota1 = aluno.querySelector('.info-nota1').textContent;
      var nota2 = aluno.querySelector('.info-nota2').textContent;
      var media = (parseFloat(nota1) + parseFloat(nota2)) / 2;

      aluno.querySelector('.info-media').textContent = media;
    });
  </script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: e se eu quiser fazer isso mas não no código HTML e sim no JavaScript?
fica igual?

Comment: Sim. Você só precisa extrair o código para seu arquivo .js e não se esquecer de no final do seu html importar o script javascript da seguinte forma:
    <script src="meuarquivo.js"></script>

Comment: obrigada! testei e deu certo!